# how to put -SELECT- in select menu

Tags: php, mysql

My question is where i have to put the the code for SELECT for select menu, i try to put in mysql but if i put the word SELECT i have to insert again all the data that related with country name. I still develop myself with php hope you guys please help me 
an example IN SELECT MENU BOX:

-SELECT-
AMERIKA

UNITED KINGDOM

KOREA

JAPAN

After i run this code from our friends it appeared Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp.... on line 411

```
       <?php
        $mysqlserver="localhost";
        $mysqlusername="root";
        $mysqlpassword="";
        $link=mysql_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

        $dbname = 'doktor';
        mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());
        ?>
        <select id="Country" name="Country">
        <option value="">- SELECT - </option>
            <?php
         $cdquery="SELECT COUNTRY, ID FROM Country";
        $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from firsttable failed: ".mysql_error());
        while ($cdrow=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
            $cdTitle =$cdrow[COUNTRY];
            $cdId = $cdrow[COUNTRY];
             ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cdId; ?>"><?php echo $cdTitle; ?></option>
         <?
            }
         ?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the HTML `<select>` tag or the MYSQL `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Don't forget to accept some answers to your questions.  You'll get more help that way.

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP will *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: all the answer i have try but still come out with Notice: Use of undefined constant COUNTRY - assumed 'COUNTRY' in C:\wamp\.... on line 216 AMERICA

Answer (score 2):

Put your Select tag outside your loop.

```
echo "<select>";
  while ( $cdrow = mysql_fetch_array( $cdresult ) ) {
    $cdTitle = $cdrow[COUNTRY];
    echo "<option>".$cdTitle."</option>";
  }
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: It probably needs to be `$cdTitle = $cdrow['COUNTRY'];` - this was in the original code without the quote, so that notice is not new.

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant COUNTRY - assumed 'COUNTRY' in C:\wamp\.... on line 216 AMERICA

Comment: is the COUNTRY your constant or just simply your field name from the table? If so, make sure it spells 'COUNTRY' but mostly table field should be 'country' then the code should be `$cdTitle = $cdrow['country'];`. Make sure you check it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
<?php
$mysqlserver = "localhost";
$mysqlusername = "root";
$mysqlpassword = "";
$link = mysql_connect(localhost, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword) or die ("Error connecting to mysql server: ".mysql_error());

$dbname = 'doktor';
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die ("Error selecting specified database on mysql server: ".mysql_error());
?>
<select id="Country" name="Country">
    <option value="">- SELECT - </option>
    <?php
    $cdquery = "SELECT COUNTRY FROM country";
    $cdresult = mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from first table failed: ".mysql_error());
    while ($cdrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cdresult)) {
        $cdTitle = $cdrow['COUNTRY'];
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cdTitle; ?>"><?php echo $cdTitle; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

If you use [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), you should use `$cdrow[0]`, or if you use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), you should use `$cdrow['COUNTRY']`. Otherwise, you wil get the notice.

Comment: Parse error: parse error in C:.. on line 411 what is the mean by that?

Comment: @NixshamBMohamad, I cannot see your actual line no of error from here :)

Comment: ERM...ok b but how suppose i do? the error is this  </tbody> 
</form>
  </p>
<p align="center">  

</body>
</html>

Comment: sithu- i just fix something from your code only i put <?php on this code    <?
    }
    ?> with this   <?php<--
    }
    ?>

Comment: Parse error: parse error in C:\wamp.... on line 411 at line </tbody> </form> </p> <p align="center"> </body> </html> after i put your code...thanks for helping me ^_^

Comment: @NixshamBMohamad, I guess your server disabled the shorten php tag, but I would recommend to use <?php instead of short form <? as most servers made it disabled by default.

Comment: sithu when i run it, it only appeared inside the form only id, name, no id and country only other fields after that dissappered with the button too...do you know what's going on?

Comment: The `ID` I added in your query is just for example. I just emphasized you to use it in `option value="..."`. The rest is just for updating by your own. You may need to debug by yourself.

Comment: @NixshamBMohamad, I'm not sure what your error is, but I removed "ID" from the query and changed to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`